# Javascript updating global variables and hoisting

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global, hoisting

I have a javascript function that uses an ajax function to post to a php script and a variable used to determine if the result comes back as true or false. In php, I would normally assign the function to a variable such as this:

```
$insert_item = $process->insert_item($item_array);

If ($insert_item->error)
{
//error detected, do something
}
```

I have not been able to accomplish this with javascript. Instead, I get a [object object] return if I assign a function to a variable. As a cheap alternative, I am trying to use a global variable to write any errors:

```
var error = false;

function update_db(formInput) {
    $.post(action.php, formInput, function(data) {

        if (data != 0) {

            error = true

        }
    });

    return error;
}

var updateDb = update_db(form_data);

if (updateDb) {

    alert("error detected");
```

In this example, 'error' comes back as false despite the ajax function updating it to true. I have read all about javascript hoisting, but have yet to find a solution. Is there anyway around this? My problem stems completely from the ajax function which I have also tried accessing directly to return any vars (like I easily do in PHP) but I have had no luck!

As a side note, I find it interesting that I can access 'error' within the ajax function (returns as false) but not able to change it.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Don't tell me how to live my life! That explains it, not sure why I didn't catch that. Facepalm, back to the drawing board.

Comment: I changed the ajax params to async: false and now it works! I finally found a cheap and easy solution to this issue. Thanks a million!

Comment: No; you found a cheap and easy way to freeze your browser.  Don't do that.

Comment: What do you recommend? I could do a callback, but it's going to be messy. I am looking at possibly trying jQuery.Deferred.

Comment: Yes; promises are the right way to do this.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/

Comment: Brilliant, got it working with promises. Thanks again!